# Meu código está retornando só metade do que deveria

Tags: python, lista

Estou fazendo uns exercícios simples em Python e esse código deveria retornar uma lista organizada pelo tamanho do nome das frutas, com a fruta com o nome mais curto em primeiro (no caso, `'uva'`).

```
lista = ['maça', 'canela', 'morango', 'uva', 'pera', 'laranja', 'banana', 'tomate', 'toranja', 'amora']
retorno = []
nome = "a"*15

while len(retorno) < len(lista):
    for nome_atual in lista:
        if len(nome_atual) < len(nome):
            nome = nome_atual
    else:
        retorno.append(nome)
        lista.remove(nome)
        nome = "a"*15

print(retorno)
```

De 10 itens, a lista de retorno só tem metade.

```
['uva', 'maça', 'pera', 'amora', 'canela']
```

Por que isso está acontecendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está na condição `while len(retorno) < len(lista)`.

Basicamente, você remove um elemento da lista original quando este é inserido no resultado. Então quando a lista `retorno` tiver 5 elementos, a lista original também terá 5 elementos restantes, e como os tamanhos delas agora são iguais, a condição do `while` não é mais satisfeita, encerrando o *loop*.

Então o que você deveria fazer é iterar enquanto tiver elementos na lista original, ou seja, `while len(lista) > 0`.

---

Mas na verdade tudo isso é bem ineficiente, pois você percorre a lista várias vezes sem necessidade. Se quer ordenar os elementos pelo tamanho, bastaria fazer:

```
retorno = sorted(lista, key=len)
```

Pois isso já retorna a lista ordenada da maneira que você quer: o parâmetro `key` indica o critério a ser usado, que no caso é a função `len`.

---

Vale lembrar também que [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) retorna outra lista, mantendo a original intacta.

Mas se quiser ordenar a própria lista, sem criar uma nova, basta usar o [método `sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

```
lista.sort(key=len)
print(lista)
```

Comment: Obrigado, eu não sabia sobre o parâmetro key no sorted().

Answer (score 2):

Uma das forma que você pode utilizar para resolver esta questão é utilizando um dos algoritmos de ordenação. Nesta questão vou dar dois exemplos utilizando o algoritmo de ordenação `bubble sort`.

O primeiro algoritmo utilizará o laço de repetição `for`, que podemos implementar da seguinte forma:

```
lista = ['maça', 'canela', 'morango', 'uva', 'pera', 'laranja', 'banana', 'tomate', 'toranja', 'amora']

n = len(lista)
for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
    for j in range(i):
        if len(lista[j]) > len(lista[j + 1]):
            lista[j], lista[j + 1] = lista[j + 1], lista[j]

print(lista)
```

E o segundo algoritmo utilizará o laço de repetição `while`, que podemos implementar da seguinte forma:

```
lista = ['maça', 'canela', 'morango', 'uva', 'pera', 'laranja', 'banana', 'tomate', 'toranja', 'amora']

n = len(lista)
while n > 0:
    i = 0
    while i < n - 1:
        if len(lista[i]) > len(lista[i + 1]):
            lista[i], lista[i + 1] = lista[i + 1], lista[i]
        i += 1
    n -= 1

print(lista)
```

Observe que ambos os códigos ordena as palavras em ordem crescente de tamanho, ou seja, da palavra de menor tamanho para a de maior tamanho. Observe também que não foi preciso criar uma outra lista. Pois, o que cada um desses algoritmos faz é simplesmente ordenar os elementos da lista.

Executando um dos dois códigos você obterá o seguinte resultado:

```
['uva', 'maça', 'pera', 'amora', 'canela', 'banana', 'tomate', 'morango', 'laranja', 'toranja']
```

---

Agora, por acaso, em um futuro próximo, desejes ordenar as palavras de mesmo tamanho em ordem alfabética, podes utilizar os respectivos códigos.

```
lista = ['maça', 'canela', 'morango', 'uva', 'pera', 'laranja', 'banana', 'tomate', 'toranja', 'amora']

n = len(lista)
for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
    for j in range(i):
        if len(lista[j]) > len(lista[j + 1]) or \
                (len(lista[j]) == len(lista[j + 1]) and lista[j] > lista[j + 1]):
            lista[j], lista[j + 1] = lista[j + 1], lista[j]

print(lista)
```

ou...

```
lista = ['maça', 'canela', 'morango', 'uva', 'pera', 'laranja', 'banana', 'tomate', 'toranja', 'amora']

n = len(lista)
while n > 0:
    i = 0
    while i < n - 1:
        if len(lista[i]) > len(lista[i + 1]) or \
                (len(lista[i]) == len(lista[i + 1]) and lista[i] > lista[i + 1]):
            lista[i], lista[i + 1] = lista[i + 1], lista[i]
        i += 1
    n -= 1

print(lista)
```

Observe que estes dois últimos códigos possuem uma condição para ordenar alfabeticamente as palavras, que porventura, possuam o mesmo tamanho.

A referida condição se encontra na seguinte linha de código:

```
(len(lista[j]) == len(lista[j + 1]) and lista[j] > lista[j + 1])
```